# How does an Operating System gets allocated its first memory space

Tags: c, memory, operating-systems

Going through `osDev.org`, I managed to write a small kernel that outputs a memory address, similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    size_t a = 2;
    size_t *p = &a;
    printf("%p\n", p);
}
```

of course `printf` is replaced with another function but the principle remains. There was an output on the monitor (an Integer) and my question is, where is that integer coming from? What is giving me the address of that first memory space to work with?